# Best way to link into SVG content

Tags: html, svg

I have some software that generates SVG images with numerous elements, such as boxes and circles. These are usually displayed in combination with HTML, either by inlining it or loading it from elsewhere.

Ideally, it would be nice to provide each SVG element with "id=" attributes in order to support URL fragments addressing those specific elements. For example, http://mypage.html#svgfrag.

Unfortunately, this seems to be less functional than the HTML equivalent. SVG 1.1 (at https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html#LinksIntoSVG) makes the following statement: "If the SVG fragment identifier addresses any element other than a ‘view’ element, then the document defined by the closest ancestor ‘svg’ element is displayed in the viewport using the view specification attributes on that ‘svg’ element.", but I cannot even get that to work in the latest Firefox. The standard doesn't define any way of going-to, selecting, or otherwise highlighting a specific element, and going to the ancestor SVG element is too  primitive.

NB: I'm using fragments on the HTML document rather than a specific SVG image displayed within it. Also, each SVG image may be constrained with scrollbars if the content is bigger than the HTML page.

Anyone have suggestions or advice for achieving something along the lines that I'm after -- something that would draw an end-user's attention to the relevant piece in a specific SVG image? Is it even possible at the moment?

Comment: Firefox supports that but only to the root SVG element, not the nearest ancestor. You can put in tabindex attributes to do highlighting if you want. That works the same as html

Comment: I don't see how tabindex would help with the selection by URL-fragment, Robert. Have I missed something?

Comment: MyDrawing.svg#MyView should focus the element, which you'll see if it has a tabindex

Comment: That would be good, Robert, but it's not working here. I tried putting id= and tabindex= on text and rect elements in Firefox 52.3.0 but the fragments have no effect at all when viewing the HTML page..

Comment: fragments only work on an SVG page, not on a html page.

Comment: Ah, not quite true. Using tabindex of 0 or -1, but not +ve values, allows a fragment on the enclosing HTML document to pull the specific SVG image into view, and the corresponding element scrolled across appropriately -- it just doesn't highlight anything. (Using Firefox 52.3.0).